# Problem with Javascript Menus on Google Map API using fusiontables

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

Right now I am currently creating a map that will have a javascript menu allowing users to change to different map views using the Google fusion table overlays. I would really appreciate it if you could help me out with a problem that is preventing me from completing the project.

This is my Google Maps HTML Page:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Met Sacramento Internship Map</title> 

<!-- Style --> 
<style> 
  body { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }
  #map_canvas { height: 500px; width:600px; }
</style> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var tableid = 567682;
    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(567682); 

  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.5213829, -122.172534);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
          layer.setMap(map);
  }
  //Change the query based on the user's selection
function changeMap(delivery) {
  layer.setQuery("SELECT Address FROM " + tableid + " WHERE delivery LIKE '" + delivery + "'");
}
</script>

 </script> 

</head> 
<body onload="initialize();">  
  Internship Status <select onchange="changeMap(this.value);"> 
    <option value="%">--Select--</option>
  <option value="ANIMALS">Animals</option>
  <option value="BUSINESS">Business</option>
  </select> <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

My problem occurs when I add this code:

```
  //Change the query based on the user's selection
function changeMap(animals) {
  layer.setQuery("SELECT Address FROM " + tableid + " WHERE Animals LIKE '" + Animals + "'");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am fairly new to fusion tables, the Google Maps API, and Javascript.

Comment: I wonder why your doctype is below the title tag...

Comment: I don't think that has to do with my question.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at table 567682, I don't see a column named "Animals". Make sure that your table contains a column named "Animals" with values "ANIMALS" and "BUSINESS" in it, since your WHERE clause is filtering on that column.

Comment: Even if I change them to my table value it doesn't work. For example if I change it to Interest Area or Address, it fails to load. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The variable Animals is not spelled correctly. In the function header you write it with lower A "animals" whereas in the query you refer with upper case "Animals"...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that Fusion table isn't playing nice with your LIKE SQL operator, even though [google says it's supported](http://code.google.com/apis/fusiontables/docs/developers_reference.html#Select)

I got it working by changing the query to use CONTAINS and option values like this:

```
layer.setQuery("SELECT Address, 'Interest Area' FROM " + tableid + " WHERE 'Interest Area' CONTAINS '" + delivery + "'"); 

<option value="Animals">Animals</option>
<option value="Business">Business</option>
```